# Is it possible to stop SonarQube from saving source code

Tags: sonarqube

We have some sensitive code that we don't want stored in Sonar's database. We do however want to record quality statistics for the code base and are happy for the file structure to be shown.

I have seen some mentions of an 'importSources' configuration parameter in old forum posts but can't find this in either the documention or the source in GitHub. I've tried adding `sonar.importSources=false` to a project properties file and it doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? It is something that I really need to work properly.

Answer (score 4):

That property has been removed.

Try [configuring the project's visibility](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-ProjectPermissions). The relevant permissions are:

- *Browse* - see 1) that the project exists, and 2) what its measures are
- *See Source Code* - see the project's uploaded source code.

This is stated explicitly in the docs, but bears repeating:

> Note that permissions are not cumulative. For instance, if you want to be able to administer the project, you also have to be granted the *Browse* permission to be able to access the project.

The same holds true for *See Source Code*. You'll first need *Browse* on the project before *See Source Code* does you any good.

Comment: As I understand it, even if nobody has browse code permissions the code will still be saved in the database. I'd really like to avoid this if at all possible.